# Circular menu to vertical switch with animation/transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am trying to achieve a animation where a button will move from its current position to top section, I have created a example here its not exactly what I am looking for but instead it just have fade in/out.

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sanjeevks121/Ltzapez6/) of working example, what I want to show is when any of the item from circular navigation is clicked, all the navigation will move to the top with sliding from center to top, so user can understand that the current menu has shifted from center to top

Here is the code I have attempt so far

EDIT: When circle menu is clicked, then the top menu will appear and circle would hide but it should so transition effect moving from center to top.

HTML

```
<div class="header noDisplay">
 <div class="logo">&nbsp;</div>
 <div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="javascript:;">Button Title</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:;">Button Title</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:;">Button Title</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:;">Button Title</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:;">Button Title</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:;">Button Title</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:;">Button Title</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
</div>
<div class="selector">
<ul>
  <li> <span><i>Button Title</i></span> </li>
  <li> <span><i>Button Title</i></span> </li>
  <li> <span><i>Button Title</i></span> </li>
  <li> <span><i>Button Title</i></span> </li>
  <li> <span><i>Button Title</i></span> </li>
  <li> <span><i>Button Title</i></span> </li>
  <li> <span><i>Button Title</i></span> </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body{padding:0; margin:0;}
.selector {position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 50%; width: 450px; height: 450px; margin-top: -225px; margin-left: -225px;}
.selector ul {position: absolute; list-style: none; padding: 0; margin: 0; top: 50px; right: 50px; bottom: 50px; left: 50px;}
.selector li {position: absolute; width: 0; height: 100%; margin: 0 50%; -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg); transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;}
.selector li span {position: absolute; left: 50%; bottom: 100%; width: 0; height: 0; line-height: 1px; margin-left: 0; background: #fff; border-radius: 50%; text-align: center; font-size: 1px; overflow: hidden; cursor: pointer; box-shadow: none; transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out, color 0.1s, background 0.1s;}
.selector li span:hover { background: #fff; }
.selector.open li span {width: 150px; height: 150px; line-height: 150px; margin-left: -75px; box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); border:1px solid #b1b1b1; font-size: 14px;
}
.noDisplay{display:none;}
.selector.open li span:hover{background:#fff;}
.circle-bg{background:#f4f4f4; border-radius:50%;}
.selector li span > i{display:block; position:absolute; top:0; padding:60px 0 0 0; background:#fff; color:#000; width:100%; font-size:24px; font-weight:bold; line-height:normal; height:100%;}
.header{float:left; width:100%; padding:5px 0 0 3%; height:75px; box-sizing:border-box; box-shadow:0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);}
.header > .logo{float:left; width:auto;}
.header > .nav{float:right; width:75%;}
.header > .nav > ul{list-style:none; margin:0; padding:0; text-align:right;}
.header > .nav > ul > li{list-style:none; display:inline-block;}
.header > .nav > ul > li > a {color: #231f1f; display: block; padding: 23px 0; margin:0 15px; font-size: 14px; text-transform: uppercase; text-decoration: none; font-family: Arial; border-bottom:2px solid #fff;}
.header > .nav > ul > li > a:hover{border-bottom:2px solid #771421; color:#771421;}
```

Comment: Hard to understand what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: When you click on circle menu item, another menu will appear on top and circle would hide, and it will show moving menu items from circle to top. hope its clear

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/eryckh8k/1/)

```
$(".selector > ul > li > span").click(function(){
    $(".logo-onload").fadeOut( "slow");
    $(".selector").css({"margin-top": "-2000px", "transition": "all 2s ease"});
    $(".header").fadeIn("slow");

})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Nirmalya but actually I want moving effect from center to top of header menus not the circle menus.

Comment: i couldn't understand what you mean. can you please explain?

Comment: On click circle menu will hide and the header will appear at the top, just have to show the transition (transition that user will see moving from center position to top area), current header just appear with fade in effect, Instead I want to fade in menu in center first and then move to top place. Hope its clear